# Presentability of the source of a fibration

Tags: ct.category-theory

Suppose I have a functor $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{B}$ that is both a Grothendieck fibration and an opfibration, $\mathcal{B}$ is presentable, and the fibres $\mathcal{E}_{b}$ for $b \in \mathcal{B}$ are all presentable. Are there any known conditions on this setup under which the category $\mathcal{E}$ will be presentable? (By "presentable" I mean the same thing as "locally presentable".)

Comment: It's worth mentioning for the benefit of passerby that sometime after asking this question, Rune and his coauthors proved an [$\infty$-categorical version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02161) of the statement in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In section 5.3 of *Accessible categories* by Makkai and Pare, they prove that if $\Phi : B^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Cat}$ is a pseudofunctor such that

1. each category $\Phi(b)$ is accessible,
2. each functor $\Phi(\beta) : \Phi(b') \to \Phi(b)$ is accessible,
3. the category $B$ is $\kappa$-accessible, and
4. the pseudofunctor $\Phi$ takes $\kappa$-filtered colimits in $B$ to weak 2-limits in $\mathrm{Cat}$.

then the total category of the Grothendieck construction of $\Phi$ is again accessible.  An accessible category is locally presentable iff it is complete iff it is cocomplete, and it is well-known that the total category of a fibration is complete if the base and fibers are complete and the restriction functors are continuous.  Moreover, an accessible functor between locally presentable categories is continuous iff it has a left adjoint, and any adjoint between locally presentable categories is accessible.  Thus, the total category of $\Phi$ is locally presentable if

1. each category $\Phi(b)$ is locally presentable,
2. each functor $\Phi(\beta) : \Phi(b') \to \Phi(b)$ has a left adjoint (i.e. the fibration is also an opfibration),
3. the category $B$ is locally $\kappa$-presentable, and
4. $\Phi$ takes $\kappa$-filtered colimits in $B$ to weak 2-limits in $\mathrm{Cat}$.

So it sounds like to your hypotheses you need only to add that $\Phi$ preserves $\kappa$-filtered (weak 2-)limits, for some $\kappa$ such that $B$ is locally $\kappa$-presentable.

Comment: Great, that's exactly the result I had hoped would be true!

Comment: Isn't the condition on $\Phi$ to preserve 2-limits, instead of 2-co-limits? This is maybe a little ambiguous in item (4) of Def. 5.3.1 in Makkai & Paré 1989 (which is what enters their Thm. 5.3.4 being invoked here) but in the prose a couple of lines below that item (4) it transpires that they require $\Phi$ to send colimiting cones in $B$ to pseudo-limiting cones in $Cat$.

Comment: @UrsSchreiber Yes, $\Phi$ sends colimits in $B$ to limits in $\rm Cat$.  This is what I meant by saying that a contravariant functor "preserves colimits", but I'll edit the post to clarify.